# Rhino Mocks - Proper usage of Arg<T>.Ref

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm having problems figuring out the proper arguments of the Arg option in RhinoMocks.

I am trying to mock the MSIRecordGetString method which has a ref Int32 parameter.  Currently I have:

```
_Api.RecordGetString(Arg<IntPtr>.Is.Anything,
                     Arg<Int32>.Is.Anything, 
                     Arg<StringBuilder>.Is.Anything, 
                     ref Arg<Int32>.Ref( ???, 0).Dummy);
```

Can anyone let me know what ??? should/could be replaced with.  I know it should be something of type AbstractConstraint but I'm not sure what is valid.  Having difficulty finding any examples of proper usage.

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm actually used to Moq, but my understanding of that first argument is a constraint, but seeing as you don't particularly care for the value (I'm assuming), could you do the following:

```
ref Arg<Int32>(Is.Anything(), 0).Dummy
```

?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the answer.  Not really sure I get the reasons for this constraint though.  Why is this different from the Out syntax which doesn't require an abstractconstraint?

Comment: Likely because out parameters have to be assigned to, whereas ref parameters do not, so the design idea is that ref parameters may have a pre-existing value to pass in.  You can constrain it at this point?

Comment: @MatthewAbbott I think `.Ref` is missing between `Arg<Int32>` and `(Is.Anything(), 0).Dummy`. So it should be `ref Arg<Int32>.Ref(Is.Anything(), 0).Dummy`.

Comment: For those reading this, don't forget the parens after `Is.Anything()`. The compiler error I got wasn't very intuitive.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose if you have to pass in a concrete class instance?